# Best practices for Asp.net Application caching with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have a web application that has some settings stored in the db.
My intention is to grab these from the db in `Application_Start()` method, and then use the memory stored values. I would also implement some way of invalidating the cache (most likely, in a way of a WCF contract, although i'm still in the planning phase for this part).

So the way i see it now is that i'd create some sort of a settings class that would store data in cache using `System.Runtime.Caching` (this is .net 4.5); this class would grab all data in it's constructor; i would then register this class interface and inject to my controllers using IoC.

I would probably register the class in singleton scope so that it's used per life of the worker process and thus the reads from the db don't happen with each request.

How much of a reinventing the wheel is this approach?

Comment: I think this would be a better question for [programmers.se]. Not downvoting or voting to close yet.

Comment: So i quickly prototyped this, doesn't seem to have any downsides for simple scenarios that i could notice so far? Also, now exploring the SqlChangeMonitor, seems like a good way for an easy app.

Comment: Also, while i got this to work, i face a logical problem - My Settings Cache is a singleton for the whole app, whereas my Database context class is created in instance per request scope. So i can't inject that to the settings cache; therefore i end up with at least two database contexts.

Comment: Instead of a singleton, why don't you have a per-request injected object with access to a single static (private) cache? Also, what is the advantage of loading in the constructor? Why not load on demand? i.e. the first request checks if its in the cache, sees it isn't so downloads it and then caches it for next request.

Comment: @berkeleybross So if i'm using MemoryCache class, will i get the same cache from these per-request objects?